What are the points of the algebra of polynomial functions on an arbitrary vector space?
Let $V$ be an arbitrary vector space over some field $\mathbb{K}$ (UPD: of characteristic 0), $V^*=\mathrm{Hom}(V,\mathbb{K})$ its linear dual. Let $\mathrm{Sym}_\mathbb{K}(V^*)$ be the free commutative $\mathbb{K}$-algebra on $V^*$, and let $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$ be the algebra of polynomial functions on $V$ (where a polynomial function is a finite sum of symmetric multilinear functions). There is a canonical embedding $\iota:\mathrm{Sym}_\mathbb{K}(V^*)\hookrightarrow\mathrm{Pol}(V)$ which is not an isomorphism unless $V$ is finite-dimensional. Now, by freeness, it is obvious that the $\mathbb{K}$-points of $\mathrm{Sym}_\mathbb{K}(V^*)$ -- i.e. unital $\mathbb{K}$-algebra homomorphisms into $\mathbb{K}$ -- correspond to linear functionals $\phi:V^*\to\mathbb{K}$, i.e. to elements of $V^{**}$. My question is, is it true that the space of $\mathbb{K}$-points of $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$ is isomorphic to $V$, and that the map on points induced by the embedding $\iota$ is the canonical inclusion of $V$ into $V^{**}$? To put it another way, is the name of $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$ justified even when $V$ is infinite-dimensional?
Notice that the question, as formulated, does not involve any topology. However, it is well-known that $V^*$ is linearly compact as the inverse limit of finite-dimensional vector spaces, and $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$ is the direct sum of completed (symmetric) tensor powers of $V^*$ with respect to this topology. It stands to reason that a linear functional $\phi:V^*\to\mathbb{K}$ should extend to an algebra homomorphism on $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$ iff it is continuous, in which case $\phi=\mathrm{ev}_v$ for some $v\in V$ -- but I can't see my way clear to a proof. On the other hand, I have the queasy feeling that, if one disregards the topology, the embedding $\iota$ might have a (non-canonical) left inverse, in which case $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$ would have (at least) $V^{**}$ worth of points -- and I can't obviously rule that out either.
It seems to me that the question is so classical that there should be a standard reference where it is settled. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Naive question from an analyst: by K-points of Pol(V), do you mean "unital K-algebra homomorphisms from Pol(V) to K"?

Your definition of polynomial function makes implicit use of polarization so I am not convinced it does the right thing in positive characteristic.

My intuition is that $\text{Hom}(\text{Pol}(V), k)$ is much bigger than $V^{\ast \ast}$. Let $P_d$ be the degree $d$ part of $\text{Pol}(V)$ and let $R_d = \sum_{i=1}^{d-1} P_i P_{d-1} \subset P_d$. Here the multiplication is ring multiplication and the sum is ring addition. So $R_d$ is a vector subspace of $P_d$; choose a complementary subspace $F_d$ such that $P_d = R_d \oplus F_d$. My intuition is that $\text{Hom}(\text{Pol}(V), k)$ is $\prod_{d=1}^{\infty} F_d^{\ast}$. This surjects onto, but is much larger than, $F_1^{\ast} = P_1^{\ast}=V^{\ast \ast}$.

Should have written $\text{Span}$ instead of $\sum$ above. The point is that $R_d$ is all degree $d$ polynomials which are sums of finitely many polynomials, where each summand factors into polynomials of lesser degree.

@YemonChoi Yes, precisely!

@QiaochuYuan actually, it does not. The definition of $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$ is as stated, the product of multilinear functions is defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ (hence is valid in any characteristic), and $\mathrm{ev}_v$ is defined by inserting $v$ in each slot of a multilinear function. Polarization need never be invoked, as I am not trying to claim that $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$ is $\mathbb{K}$-point-determined (which indeed is false in positive characteristic). In fact, I "secretly" have in mind the super/graded commutative case, where polarization fails even in characteristic 0.

@DavidESpeyer Your intuition is exactly my "queasy feeling". Let $U_d$ be the subalgebra generated by $P_{\leq d}$. These form a filtration on $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$; in particular, $U_1$ is $\mathrm{Sym}_\mathbb{K}(V^*)$ (rather, its image under $\iota$). Your argument goes through if this filtration has a multiplicative splitting -- but it's not clear that it does (i.e. that products of your arbitrarily chosen $F$'s do not have components in the $R$'s).

@DavidESpeyer Even if a multiplicative splitting does exist, there is at any rate no canonical one. However, $V\mapsto\mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Pol}(V),\mathbb{K})$ is an endofunctor on $\mathbf{Vect}_\mathbb{K}$. If it is "much bigger than $V^{**}$", what could it be?

@YemonChoi edited the question with a clarification in response to your comment.

@QiaochuYuan my apologies: I now realize you probably meant that $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$, as I defined it, is not isomorphic to the algebra of polynomials in $\mathrm{dim}(V)$ variables in prime characteristic -- which is, of course, true -- so the name is misleading in that case. I stand corrected. One can still meaningfully ask the question about $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$ in char=p, but David Speyer's answer applies to the inverse limit of polynomial algebras (over a perfect $\mathbb{K}$), which is different. I'm perfectly happy to stick to char=0, though, so I'll make an update to that effect.

@DavidESpeyer I had realized that a multiplicative splitting of the filtration $U$ was tantamount to a non-canonical isomorphism of $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$ with a free commutative algebra on the direct sum of the $F$'s, which would imply that its  points were as you said -- but didn't believe that could be true. Snowden et al's result proves me wrong, of course. Thanks for digging it up!

I asked Andrew Snowden this question, and he pointed me to his paper "Big Polynomial rings and Stillman's Conjecture", with Dan Erman and Steven Sam.   This paper assumes the axiom of choice.
Summary: At least if $V$ is countable dimensional and the field $k$ is perfect, things work as I imagined.
Specifically, let $k$ be a perfect field and let $R$ be the graded inverse limit $\lim\limits_{\infty \leftarrow n} k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. This is the same as the OP's ring, when $V$ is a countable dimensional vector space over $k$. Let $R_+$ be the ideal of positive degree elements of $R$.
Theorem 1.2 of the paper states that $R$ is a polynomial ring. In particular, if $\{ f_i \}$ is any set of elements of $R_+$ which form a basis for the $k$ vector space $R_+/R_+^2$, then $R$ is a polynomial ring in the $f_i$.
So giving a $k$-algebra homomorphism $R \to k$ is equivalent to giving a linear map $R_+/(R_+)^2 \to k$. Note that $R_+/(R_+)^2$ breaks up into graded summands $\bigoplus (R_+)_j/(R_+)^2_j$, so $\left( \bigoplus (R_+)_j/(R_+)^2_j \right) = \prod_j \left((R_+)_j/(R_+)^2_j \right)^{\ast}$. This surjects onto the first factor. We have $(R_+)_1 = V^{\ast}$ and $(R_+)^2_1 = 0$, so this first factor is $V^{\ast \ast}$, confirming that the set of ring homs surjects on $V^{\ast \ast}$, but is much larger.

Excellent! (though contrary to my expectations) In fact, in char 0 one can easily show, in a coordinate-free way and for an arbitrary $V$, that $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$ has enough derivations in the sense of Def. 2.1 of Snowden et. al.'s paper (those of the form $\iota_v$, $v\in V$ suffice), then invoke Thm 2.2 of the paper (which applies in this generality) to conclude that $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$ is isomorphic to a free graded algebra. In char $p$ $\mathrm{Pol}(V)$ is not a polynomial algebra even for a f.d. $V$, but I'm happy to drop that case.
